# Inheritance on private members

Tags: java, inheritance

```
    class Quadrilateral
    {
        private Point TL;
        private Point TR;
        private Point BR;
        private Point BL;
        public Quadrilateral(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4)
        {
            TL = p1;
            TR = p2;
            BR = p3;
            BL = p4;
        }

    } 
class Point
{
public double x;
public double y;
    Point(double a, double b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }

}
class trapezoid extends Quadrilateral
{
    public trapezoid(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4)
    {
        super(p1,p2,p3,p4);
    }
        public double areaofTrapezoid()
        {
            return ((((TR.x-TL.x)+(BR.x-BL.x))/2)*(TL.y-BL.y));
        }
}
```

I am trying to access the x and y values in TR,TL,BR and BL, but i do not wanna make functions like getxofTL, getyofTL, getxofBR...etc in class quadrilateral. how else can i access those value in my subclass without changing the access specifier for the variables.

Comment: Why would you not want to make setters/getters? If you are using an IDE most of the time they will do it for you.

Comment: Make GetTL, GetTR, etc instead. Then you can say `GetTR().x`. Or just make TL, TR, etc public.

Comment: Do you want them private, or do you want to avoid getters/setters? You can't have it both ways.

Comment: If you only want to access them from subclasses, make them protected.

Comment: gotcha. protected is not an option in this case. so i guess i'll settle for getters. i guess there really is no other way to do it. thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

Private members cannot be accessed directly by subclasses (as opposed to *protected* members). So unless you want to use reflection (which you shouldn't!), you should use public/protected accessors.

I can't think of any reason why you wouldn't want such getters other than the potential hassle involved in creating them. Note that most IDEs can do this for you automatically.

For reference, see [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: gotcha. well. it's not like i "dont want to" i was just trying to find out if there is any other way apart from that. i think i'll use getters. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have to either make these fields public or add getter methods. Making getter methods is generally preferred to making fields public.

Here is a useful page about access specifiers, including a handy table: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Source: AP Computer Science class

Comment: Or you can make them protected.

Comment: so i have to do either of the two then? i was wondering if there is any other way. haha

Comment: I added a link to my answer.

Comment: @RJ As far as I am aware, there is no other way unless you make more drastic changes.